# What iss the 'index' element of tuple returned from inspect.getouterframes() function?

Tags: python, callstack

I did a `help(inspect.getouterframes)` on python, and here's what it gave me:

```
getouterframes(frame, **context**=1)
Get a list of records for a frame and all higher (calling) frames.

Each record contains a frame object, filename, line number, function
name, a list of lines of context, and **index within the context**.
```

What do these "context" and "index" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's to add some context from the surrounding code for the current line. Simple example:

```
import sys
import inspect

def f():
    # prev
    return sys._getframe()
    # next

# prev
framelist = inspect.getouterframes(f(), 3)
# next

for frame in framelist:
    print frame[3], "context:\n"
    for i, line in enumerate(frame[-2]):
        print line.rstrip(),
        if i == frame[-1]:
            print ' *** index ***'
        else:
            print
    print
```

Output:

```
f context:

    # prev
    return sys._getframe()  *** index ***
    # next

<module> context:

# prev
framelist = inspect.getouterframes(f(), 3)  *** index ***
# next
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` element of `FrameInfo` is the index into `FrameInfo.context` for the supplied line.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack):

> The tuple contains the frame object, the filename, the line number of
> the current line, the function name, a list of lines of context from
> the source code, and the index of the current line within that list.